# Arreglos en estructura JSON

Tags: laravel, json, laravel-6

Me gustaria saber como puedo cambiar la estructura de una respuesta json desde laravel, ya que retorna los datos encerrados en un par de corchetes y dentro los enumera, lo cual no es muy conveniente para imprimir las variables ya que tengo que agregar el numero para acceder a los datos, aquí un ejemplo de la respuesta:

```
"created_at": "2020-05-31 20:20:40",
    "updated_at": "2020-05-31 20:20:40",
    "languages": [
        "Español"
    ],
    "location": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "country": "Mexico",
            "add_line_1": "Priv Zarco #26",
            "add_line_2": "Santa fe 5ta seccion",
            "post_code": "22664",
            "city": "Tijuana",
            "state": "Baja California",
            "user_id": 2,
            "created_at": "2020-05-31 20:20:40",
            "updated_at": "2020-05-31 20:20:40"
        }
    ],
```

necesito que en Location quite los dos corchetes dejando solo las llaves, asi:

```
"created_at": "2020-05-31 20:20:40",
    "updated_at": "2020-05-31 20:20:40",
    "languages": [
        "Español"
    ],
    "location": {
            "id": 2,
            "country": "Mexico",
            "add_line_1": "Priv Laguna #32",
            "add_line_2": "Santa fe 5ta seccion",
            "post_code": "22664",
            "city": "Tijuana",
            "state": "Baja California",
            "user_id": 2,
            "created_at": "2020-05-31 20:20:40",
            "updated_at": "2020-05-31 20:20:40"
        },
```

espero me entiendan y me puedan ayudar, mi controlador esta configurado asi:

```
$user = User::findOrFail($id);

            // Aqui inicia la consulta de la locacion, nota: es una tabla relacionada hasMany
            $user->location;
            $myLanguages = Language::where('user_id', $id)->get('language');
            $user->languages = Arr::pluck($myLanguages, 'language');
            $user->dob = Carbon::parse($user->dob)->format('l, d F Y');
            $user->social_links;
```

Comment: Pero si es una relación hasMany está bien que sea un array... Por qué sacar los corchetes? Y algo que no se entiende ahí, es cómo llegas de ese código a un json como el que muestras.

Comment: entonces el error podria estar en el tipo de relacion? respecto a porque quitar los corchetes, es porque estoy trabajando con vuejs y el componente asi lo requiere, si no esta en esa estructura no puedo acceder a la informacion a menos que a las variables les agregue el indice al final, lo cual lo convierte en un problema si hablamos de un array

Comment: No digo que sea un error, sino que una relación `hasMany` te va a devolver una colección (que se transforma en array al pasarla a json) pues son muchos los objetos. Si un usuario puede tener muchas Location relacionadas, la relación sería correcta. Ahora, si un usuario puede tener solo una Location, la relación sería `hasOne`,  y ahí sí, en vez de una colección, va a devolver un solo objeto.

Comment: Buen punto, dejame lo corrijo y te aviso va?